# icon and text in next line

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome

I have some icons with text like as shown below

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02fmv4Lb/)

```
<span class="text-center  m-sm">
  <span class="fa fa-circle fa-1x"></span>
  <span class="font-bold no-margins">
    testdevice 1
  </span>
</span>

<span class="text-center  m-sm">
  <span class="fa fa-circle fa-1x"></span>
  <span class="font-bold no-margins">
    testdevice 2
  </span>
</span>

<span class="text-center  m-sm">
  <span class="fa fa-circle fa-1x"></span>
  <span class="font-bold no-margins">
    testdevice 3
  </span>
</span>
```

Can anyone please tell me how to make the icon and text in two rows like as shown below without using any specified width or height

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Adding `display: block;` to your `span` would do it.

```
.text-center{
   text-align: center;
   display: inline-block;
   margin: 0 5%;
}
span{
   display: block;
}
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/02fmv4Lb/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `block` and `inline block` display properties

inline block for the containers and block for the children

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/02fmv4Lb/2/)

Answer (score 1):

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/priyasingh/02fmv4Lb/3/)

```
.text-center{
  text-align:center;
}

.m-sm {
  display: inline-block;  
}

.m-sm span { display: block; }
```